# veryfying the output of a string in a certain format

Tags: python, string, format

I am trying to check whether or not a licence plate fits a certain format when the user inputs a number plate. It needs to be in the format of two numbers, three letters, and finally two more numbers. If it does not match this format then it must save it to a list.

```
speed_limit = []
while True :
    speed = float()
    distance = 50

    time=float(raw_input('enter time'))

    speed = distance / time
    print speed

    if speed > 31.2928:
        #70 mph converted into meters per second
        number_plate = raw_input('enter number plate')
        number_plate.upper()
        speed_limit.append(number_plate)
        print speed_limit
    else:
        print 'ok'
```

This is my current code, I am not sure if this is possible or I am asking a too vague question but I need help!

Comment: the speed_limit is the start of the code sorry ;_;

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regular expression match. The regex key that you would be needing is

```
(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2})
```

This returns 2 numbers, 3 letters and 2 numbers. You can try more regex combinations [here](http://www.regexr.com/)

Try the following lines in your command prompt to check the code-

```
import re
m = re.match('(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2})','12MNB36')
```

m holds the result if the string matched the pattern or not.